# Nonlinear Color Gradients For Heatmap R

Tags: r, colors, heatmap

I have a 1941 x 119 matrix of values ranging in [-2, 2], and highly clustered around zero.

[image: histogram clustered around 0]

I want to create a heatmap that reveals clusters I already discovered with hclust. I want to use a diverging color ramp so that values range from green to red while getting darker (or lighter) in the center. The trouble is the data is so clustered around zero that linear color ramps like redgreen(n) and RColorBrewer fail to capture the subtle variance and yield washed out plots.

I tried to build a color ramp using "colorpanel" in {gplots} and a sigmoid function to specify break points in my data like so:

```
library(gplots)

lower <- -1
upper <- 1
growth_rate <- 0.05
# Returns break pts b/w [-1,1]
sig <- function(x) {
  return(lower + ((upper-lower)/(1+exp(-growth_rate*x))))
}

breaks <- sig(seq(-30, 30, by=1.0)) 
breaks <- append(-2, append(breaks, 2)) # Append min and max break pts
ramp <- colorpanel(n=length(breaks)-1, low="green", mid="black", high="red")
```

Then I ran my heatmap:

```
# 'data' is a 1941 x 119 matrix
heatmap.2(data, main="Heatmap Sigmoid",col=ramp, trace='none', breaks=breaks)
```

[image: muddy heatmap]

Anyone know a way to build a color ramp that can reveal those values all getting thrown into the (shades of) "black" bin?

Comment: EDIT: Fixed image uploads

Answer (score 0):

Your general solution is correct, but your method of generating the breaks doesn't give good results. How about a color scheme based on the quantiles of your data?

```
# Some fake data:
data = matrix(sample(
  c(
    rgamma(1941*119, shape = 0.3, rate = 5),
    -rgamma(1941*119, shape = 0.3, rate = 5)
  ), 
  5000), nrow = 250) 
# similar to your histogram
hist(data)

# make breaks using data quantiles
breaks = quantile(data, probs = seq(0,1,0.1)
ramp <- colorpanel(n=length(breaks)-1, low="green", mid="black", high="red")
heatmap.2(data, main="Heatmap Sigmoid",col=ramp, trace='none', breaks=breaks)
```

You could mess with quantiles further to specify more breaks than just the 10%, 20% etc. Or try other transformations of your data, e.g. square-root, log, etc.